# Why I can't connect to mysql docker container through JDBC with another database user than root?

Tags: mysql, docker

I am using [official docker container from mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql).

I've run docker container with this commands]:

```
sudo docker run -d --name desarrollo -p 3306:3306 -h localhost -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin --mount src=mysql-desarrollo,dst=/var/lib/mysql mysq
```

Then I connected:

```
sudo docker exec -it desarrollo mysql -u root -p
```

It worked. Althougth I don't know why I have a root user with host '%'

```
mysql> select user, host from mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| user             | host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | %         |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost |
| mysql.session    | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
+------------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Then I performed these sentences for create a database and its user:

```
create database my_database CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;
create user 'my_user'@'localhost' identified by 'my_password';
grant ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'my_user'@'localhost';
```

I asignned all privileges because when I only asignned privileges over my created database it didn't work.

Now, When I  try to connect with my_user user through JDB it doesn't work but with root user it works (It was tested with internal client on Intellij IDE). This the JDBC url:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because your `my_user` is allowed to access from `localhost`. But this is referred to `localhost` inside the docker container. But you're trying to access from the host PC. So replacing it with your PC IP address or using wild card would work.

```
create user 'my_user'@'%' identified by 'my_password';
```

Comment: It works! I didn't know that '%' was a wildcard character. Thanks!